# Percentage of a set of numbers

Tags: algorithm, percentage

I’ve been asked to make a chart that displays how many users are on each page. This chart will be color-coded, where the page with the most users will have 100% opacity, the page with the least viewers will have 40% opacity and the pages in between will have a corresponding opacity.

So, I have a set of numbers, I need

- The largest number to be 100%
- The smallest number to be 40%
- The numbers in between to fall between 100% and 40%

The numbers can be any whole number 1 or greater.

So given 1000, 500, 100, 50

- 1000 should be 100%
- 500 should be ??
- 100 should be ??
- 50 should be 40%

Or, given 2, 1

- 2 should be 100%
- 1 should be 40%

Or given 1000, 1

- 1000 should be 100%
- 1 should be 40%

Or given 7485, 395, 3

- 7485 should be 100%
- 395 should be ??
- 3 should be 40%

I hope that makes sense.

What equation can I use to solve this?

I know to get the percent is just `(# / largest_number) * 100` but I’m lost trying to get it between 100% and 40%

The closest I could get is `((#/largest_number) * 60) + 40`, but that assumes 0 is the smallest number and gives me 43 for my smallest number in the 1st set of numbers (50) instead of 40% like I need.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of getting the percent with `(# / largest_number) * 100` do `x = ((# - lowest_number) / (largest_number - lowest_number) * 100`

This is a basic normalization function - [see here for details](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/70801/how-to-normalize-data-to-0-1-range).

This way `largest number` will always map to `1` and `lowest_number` will always map to `0`, then you can interpolate using your function `(x * 60) + 40`

Comment: Looks like I would be best off losing the `*100 ` in your suggestion to keep it between `1 ` and `0 ` but this EXACTLY what I was looking for, thank you!

Comment: Indeed, you don't need the `*100`!